# Creating a "external" timeline progress bar for video analysis

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, video

I am creating a small video analysis app, and I want to create a progress bar which is similar to the iphone functionality when cropping a video or image, there is a bar with vertical lines and you can then with touch scroll left or right and the settings change. I'm trying to make the same but with video, so when I scroll right it "goes forward" in the video timeline and when I go back it goes back. It's the same as the video timeline on the iphone, but without the frames and instead vertical "lines" that extend horiztonally.

I've been trying to find any javascript libraries or existing work - but without any luck, so I'm hoping someone can help me get started here. I'm using video.js (does not need to be this), and then I'm targeting the progress bar and making an external version outside of the video, but I don't know how to continue from there.

Here's my current code, and images of what I'm trying to accomplish.

What I'm aiming for:
[image: My goal]

Iphone's functionality:
[image: Iphone editing options]

```
<div class="col-4 ml-n4 mr-n4 pl-n4 container ">
    <div class="video-container" style="position: relative; overflow:hidden; width: 400px; height: 500px;">
    <div id="zoomContainer1" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
        <video
            id="series_1"
            class="video-js vjs-theme-sea vjs-nofull"
            preload="auto"
            width="400"
            height="500"
            poster=""
            controls
            muted
            loop
            autoplay
            data-setup='{
            "controls": false,
            "playbackRates": [0.3, 0.5, 1]
            }'
        >
            {% if videos %}
                <source src="{{ videos.0.url }}" type="video/mp4" />
            {% else %}
                <source src="" type="video/mp4" />
            {% endif %}
        </video>
    </div>
</div>


<!-- Custom Progress Bar for Player 1 -->
<div class="custom-progress-container">
  <div id="customProgressBar1" class="custom-progress-bar">
   <!-- Custom Timeline progress bar here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

```
/*************** PROGRESS BAR ***************/
.custom-progress-bar {
    background-color: #4d4d4d;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0%;
}

.custom-progress-container {
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 10px; /* Adjust height as needed */
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```